# Make stream_socket_server to stay functional after first received data package

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, stream

I'm trying to make tcp socket server to create and maintain persistent bidirectional communications, via PHP's `stream_socket_server()`.

> **Short version of question:**
>
> how to have tcp server created with `stream_socket_server()` staying
>   alive - not failing to receive data after first successful data
>   reception which is in my case one single character typed in terminal after telnet
>   command?

**Long version - what exactly I expect to achieve**

Just for illustration, look at communication type when telneting some host with smtp server. You type in terminal `telnet somehost 25` and get welcome response and (usually) smtp banner. *And connection persists.* Than you type hello command, and you get, again, response with option to proceed issuing further commands. *Again, connection persists*, you got response and option to continue. This is exact communication type I'm after.

**What have I done so far**

this code:

```
<?php

$server = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:4444", $errno, $errorMessage);

if ($server === false) throw new UnexpectedValueException("Could not bind to socket: $errorMessage");

for (;;)  {
    $client = stream_socket_accept($server);

    if ($client) 
    {
        echo 'Connection accepted from ' . stream_socket_get_name($client, false) . "\n";
        echo "Received Out-Of-Band: " . fread($client, 1500) . "\n";
        #fclose($client);
    } 

}
```

which works fine if you are just trying to send data (once per shot) via another PHP script i.e. `stream_socket_client()`.

Server created by this script fails to maintain connection type I have described. After doing `telnet localhost 4444` I'm switched into terminal mode to write message. When I do so, on the server side **I got first typed character caught up and - nothing more**. Whatever I've tried, I couldn't catch new packages sent from client side by typing. Like `stream_socket_accept()` blocks or ignores all after first character-data package received. 
So, what am I doing wrong - how to solve this issue?

Comment: You might learn something it you add a long timeout value to your stream_socket_accept call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is only doing a single read before it loops back to accept another incoming connection.

The [documentation for fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) states that it will return as soon as a packet has been received.  That is, it won't wait for the full 1500 bytes.

Given the slow speed of human typing, you end up sending a packet with a single character to your server which is returned and then it goes on to accept another incoming connection.

Put a loop around your read as such:

```
for (;;)  {
    $client = stream_socket_accept($server);

    if ($client) {
        echo 'Connection accepted from ' . stream_socket_get_name($client, false) . "\n";
        for (;;) {
            $data = fread($client, 1500);
            if ($data == '') break;
            echo "Received Out-Of-Band: " . $data . "\n";
        }
        fclose($client);
    } 
}
```